# Timeseries data query - optimizing query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, query-optimization

Quick question on optimizing a query type we do a lot in working with time-series data provided by a data logging system.

Database is SQL Server 2019 (v15) and for simplification assume the table is made up of just:

- `ID` (bigint) - unique ID for the row
- `Timestamp` (bigint) - Unix timestamp value.
- `Sample` (float) - Value of sample taken (e.g. temperature measurement).

There is no regular interval or spacing with respect to timestamp as the data logger only logs data on a change to the data point being monitored (i.e. there is no reliable way to determine when in time that a previous sample would have been taken).

Anyway, our queries often involve selecting a range of data between two timestamps, but as expected the timestamps selected as the bounds for the range rarely ever line-up exactly with a timestamp in the data set. Because of this, what we really need to select is all the data in the range **plus** one record immediately before the range (so we know what the data value is leading into the selected range).

Historically we have done this one of two ways:

1. Select the rows between the timestamps (inclusive) and union this with a top(1) select of the first row with a timestamp <= to the range start.
   OR
2. Select the top(1) timestamp <= to the range start into a variable and then do a select statement with this new timestamp as the lower bound for the range.

Since I am not an expert, I'm wondering if either one of these methods has better performance over the other or if there is maybe some better, third option we haven't encountered.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have an index on `timestamp` both solutions are pretty much equivalent in terms of performance. Both should be pretty fast. Anyway, I would get the execution plan for both and then I would compare.

Comment: Yes index on `timestamp` is important and to check the execution plan actually uses it, comparing estimated rows to rows read and actual rows returned. Can't really say anything else without seeing the query, if you only need the columns mentioned then make sure the index is covering.

Comment: Yes, `timestamp` is indexed. Thanks.

Comment: Check to verify that the query execution plan is performing index seeks (not scans) for the UNIONed part of the query.